# How can I stop taking the second text/barcode on Entry (Textbox) in Xamarin using IsReadyOnly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an application where I am having to scan the barcodes and each barcode is being processed and everything looks OK.
I am only getting an issue with the textbox(Entry), when the user scan the second barcode while first is being processed, as the second barcode-text appends with the first one with in the textbox(txtBarcode).

I want to stop taking any text/barcode, until the first barcode finishes its process. So I have used IsReadyOnly property for not taking any further text/barcode during a scanning process but It is not working for me.

//Code:
Created textbox event:

```
txtBarcode.ReturnCommand = new Command(async () => await KeyEnteredOn_Barcode_TextBox_Async());
```

//When Scan any barcode then It calls the below method:

```
    private async Task KeyEnteredOn_Barcode_TextBox_Async()
    {
     
        try
        {  ....
             txtBarcode.IsReadOnly = true;
           //Process Barcode..

        }catch(Exception e) {}
         finally {  txtBarcode.IsReadOnly = false; }
```

Comment: Why not temporarily disable whatever barcode reader you're using while the barcode is being "processed"

Comment: Use a private bool variable to know when you are already processing.

Comment: @Andrew, I am not using any barcode Library to do so.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I am having a problem with Xamarin textbox(Entry), it is not letting me disable/readonly  to stop taking any further barcode. 
I had checked with private variables, but user still able to scan barcode even textbox is Unfocused but it is appending the barcode text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes，just as ToolmakerSteve said, you can use a bool variable to indicate whether data is being processed:

```
// True if data is being processed.
public static bool IsProcessing = false;
```

The logic looks like this：

```cs
if (IsProcessing)
{   // Re-entered while still processing.

    //Store the second (third, etc) barcodes in a queue...
}
else
{
    IsProcessing = true;
    try
    {
        //Process Barcode...
        
        //while any stored barcodes (2nd, 3rd), process them also...
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        IsProcessing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe, I can not solve this problem with the code/logic, I am having the issue with Xamarin-textbox (Entry),  lets make it easy, How can I Disable the textbox to stop taking any text in Xamarin.  I have checked IsEnabled=False   and IsReadOnly = True,  both are not working for me.

Comment: I've fixed the logic, which was handling re-entry incorrectly. If you want to skip extra bar codes, do nothing in the re-entry part. That's just like disabling the textbox.